# Maximal number of hops (path cost) in Thread / OpenThread

Tags: iot, mesh-network, openthread

What is the maximal number of hops (or path cost) allowed by Thread specification.
How many hops are supported by [OpenThread](https://github.com/openthread/openthread)?

I found two similar questions ([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326438/is-it-possible-to-connect-300-devices-with-openthread), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37449796/how-many-hops-does-openthread-support#:%7E:text=1%20Answer&text=The%20maximum%20path%20cost%20amount,with%20good%20links%20is%2016.)) but answer is different (maybe even outdated?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread specifies a maximum path cost of 16 between routers. Link cost between routers can be 1, 2, or 4. Links to end devices are not included in the path cost calculation.